# ORA-00933 error but the query have correct clauses

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have "ORA-00933: sql command not properly ended" error in this query:

```
SELECT FILIALE_CHIUSA FROM FILIALI_CHIUSE WHERE FILIALE IN (9909);
```

The table is

```
CREATE TABLE FILIALI_CHIUSE (
                              FILIALE NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL,
                              FILIALE_CHIUSA NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL
                           );
```

I have checked but the query seems right and with not erroneous clauses, so where is the problem?

Comment: Sidenote: If checking for one value only, don't use IN, but =

Comment: It's not reproducible https://dbfiddle.uk/AMzmk0WK

Comment: How (and where) are you running the query? Some languages and tools execute a single statement and will baulk at the semicolon statement separator - e.g. JDBC, `execute immediate`, and some ways of running in some IDEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the final semicolon, that wasn't processed correctly. Removing it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid `create table` statement; Oracle doesn't support `if not exists`.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FILIALI_CHIUSE (
  2                                FILIALE NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL,
  3                                FILIALE_CHIUSA NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL
  4                             );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FILIALI_CHIUSE (
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Without that clause:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE FILIALI_CHIUSE
  2    (FILIALE NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL,
  3     FILIALE_CHIUSA NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL
  4    );

Table created.
```

`select` also works (though, doesn't return anything as table is empty):

```
SQL> SELECT FILIALE_CHIUSA FROM FILIALI_CHIUSE WHERE FILIALE IN (9909);

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: The problem isn't in this! The table is created correctly! The problem is in the other query!

Comment: It is not, as demonstrated. Could you, please, post your own session so that we could **exactly** see what you did and how Oracle responded? If you don't use SQL*Plus (as I did) but some GUI, post a screenshot.